# Expanded in Column but throwing Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget

Tags: flutter

I was using an `Expanded` widget within a `FutureBuilder` directly in a column and all was well. However, adding a `RefreshIndicator` widget seems to have broken things and I can't see why.

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Row(...),
          FutureBuilder(
            future: ...,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              return RefreshIndicator(
                onRefresh: ...,
                child: getList(snapshot.connectionState, user),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );


Widget getList(ConnectionState connectionState, UserRepository user) {
    switch (connectionState) {
      case ConnectionState.done:
        return Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: number,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return GestureDetector(
                onTap: ...,
                child: Card(
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      ...,
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          padding: ...,
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                "",
                                softWrap: false,
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                "",
                                softWrap: false,
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      default:
        return const Text("other");
    }
  }
```

Error:

```
The following assertion was thrown while applying parent data.:
Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.

The ParentDataWidget Expanded(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of type FlexParentData to a RenderObject, which has been set up to accept ParentData of incompatible type StackParentData.

Usually, this means that the Expanded widget has the wrong ancestor RenderObjectWidget. Typically, Expanded widgets are placed directly inside Flex widgets.
The offending Expanded is currently placed inside a Stack widget.

The ownership chain for the RenderObject that received the incompatible parent data was:
  _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#85a8f] ← NotificationListener<ScrollMetricsNotification> ← Scrollable ← PrimaryScrollController ← ListView ← Expanded ← NotificationListener<OverscrollIndicatorNotification> ← NotificationListener<ScrollNotification> ← Stack ← RefreshIndicator ← ⋯
```

I've looked at other posts with similar error and they just talk about using expanded within a Column, which I'm already doing, so I'm lost. I'm trying to get my list view to be the remaining height of the screen, which was working before adding `RefreshIndicator`.

Comment: I've try to simplify the snippet by removing unnecessary part and failed to reproduce the error. Can you provide full minimal snippet(same structure)

Comment: @YeasinSheikh When you say "removing unnecessary part", what are you referring to?

Comment: ` onTap: ...,` and others switch cases

Comment: @YeasinSheikh It isn't visible but `onTap` is needed as I'm doing something when it is tapped. As for the switch cases, there are only two, `ConnectionState.done` and `default` so I'm not following that

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, although I'm sure it's the best one.

I removed the `Expanded` directly surrounding the `ListView` and added a `Column` and two `Expanded`s inside the `FutureBuilder`.

```
return Expanded(
    child: RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: () {
            return user.fetchUserEvents(client, Environment().config.baseApiUrl, user.userId);
        },
        child: Column(
            children: [
                Expanded(
                    child: getList(snapshot.connectionState, user),
                ),
            ],
        ),
    ),
);
```